# Exception uploading data via Data Loader: Too many @future calls

Tags: apex, data-loader

I can't code - a consultant helps us develop our Salesforce but is on holiday. I'm trying to upload to a custom object but get this error code on all entries using the Apex Data Uploader:

> TDTM_PeaceRegisterEntry: System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 51.

I need to upload the data quickly - is there any non-code way to solve this problem?

Comment: can you add your trigger code here.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a @Future call in his trigger (maybe in a loop)

try to upload with less batch size (<50)

Comment: No need to wait, actually. The limit is 50 per transaction, but there's no limit to how many can be queued.

Comment: @sfdcfox you are right, I edited my answer the only other limit is the number of Future call per 24 hours